# toFixed in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

If incoming number is intiger for example 12 I want it to be saved in db like this 12.00. Even if I mannualy write { price: 12.00 } it still saves it as 12. I tried use toFixed(2) but that didn't work, it looks like this is default behaviour of mongodb. The others numbers like 12.99 are being saved correctly

```
const ProductSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    price: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    }
})
```

```
const product = new Product({
        price: req.body.price,
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a number, not a String. 12 and 12.00 are saved in the same way. It's only dependent when you read it and convert it to String.

Comment: if it the answer you requested, please approve it as the official answer